# WAMP component for celery task monitoring and publishing to React app

Tags: python, celery, publish-subscribe, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I have a React app that POST over Klein and runs a Celery job async (via RabbitMQ). I would like to display all tasks in some table with status updates via a WAMP Pub/Sub (I'm using Crossbar as a router). My React table component gets the initial data and subscribes to changes as such:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.session //Autobahn session variable passed down as prop
      .subscribe("celery.update.task", (args,kwargs,details)=>{update state})
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //Gets all tasks in db (SQLite)
    this.props.session.call("celery.all.tasks", (a,k,d)=>{set initial state}
  }
  render() {
    //render table with data from state
  }
```

I'm currently trying to get the WAMP components on the backend (using AutobahnPython) to publish "celery.update.task" on celery events. This application will be internet-facing so I would like to use secure websockets (wss) and so followed [this](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/pubsub/tls) tutorial for running the WAMP components. My current issue is that the WAMP component meant to [listen to celery events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159394/how-to-monitor-events-from-workers-in-a-celery-django-application) does not publish async (once the python process is ended, all publishes then get sent):

```
import threading, time, ast, six
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunnner
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
from twisted.internet._sslverify import OpenSSLCertificateAuthorities
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
from OpenSSL import crypto

class MonitorThread(ApplicationSession):
  @inlineCallbacks
  def onJoin(self, details):
    from app_queue import celery #Celery instance
    self.celery_app = celery
    self.interval = 1
    self.state = self.celery_app.events.State()
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
    self.thread.daemon = True
    self.thread.start()
    yield 

  @inlineCallbacks
  #there are analogous callbacks for "received", "started" and "failed"
  def handle_task_success(self, event):
    ...
    res = yield self.publish("celery.task.update", "some_task_update") 
    resultValue(res)

  def run(self): 
    while True:
      try:
        with self.celery_app.connection() as connection: 
          recv = self.select_app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
            "task-succeeded": self.handle_task_success
          })
          recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)
      except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
      except Exception:
        pass
      time.sleep(self.interval)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,six.u(open('.crossbar/example.cert.pem', "r").read()))
  options = CertificateOptions(trustRoot=OpenSSLCertificateAuthorities([cert]))
  runner = ApplicationRunner(url=u"wss://127.0.0.1:443/ws", realm=u"realm1", ssl=options)
  runner.run(MonitorThread)
```

The above code is able to monitor all events but the publish methods aren't pushed to subscribers until the python process is ended. I would like for the WAMP component to publish to "celery.task.update" on every Celery event (received, started, succeeded, failed) so that the Table component is live updated.

Is there a way to make this work? I've tried without success trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163550/calling-publish-from-outside-a-custom-autobahn-wampclientprotocol?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549370/how-to-send-autobahn-twisted-wamp-message-from-outside-of-protocol).